# Dynamics CRM Report deployment for embedded connection

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I am developing Dynamics CRM reports using fetchXML for my online instance. Since they need embedded connection string, my connection information is instance specific. So, for sandbox i need to deploy a specific RDL and i need to change the RDL with production connection string when deploying on prod.

I feel like i am missing something here, changing the connection string manually doesnt seem right. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry about connection string. When you deploy report to CRM your connection string is not used and overridden with environment specific connection string.